# Read XML Attribute values based on another attribute value in the same node using Powershell

Tags: xml, powershell

I have a XML file `file1.xml` which has the data like below.

```xml
<Tag1>
<Tag2>      
  <file Name="file1.rdl" Path="folder34" />
  <File Name="file2.rdl" Path="folder37" />
  <File Name="file3.rdl" Path="folder34" />
  <File Name="File4.rdl" Path="folder76" />
  <File Name="file5.rdl" Path="folder37" />
</Tag2>
</Tag1>
```

I Need a PowerShell script which will return the value of the `Path` attribute based on the `Name` attribute value.

Example:

If I pass the value "File4.rdl" it should return the value as "Folder76".

I Wrote the command to read the XML data and stored the data in an array `$Test`.

```bsh
[xml]$XmlDocument = Get-Content "D:\Roshan\Testing\Test1.xml"

$Test = $XmlDocument.Tag1.Tag2.file | Select-Object Name, Path

Write-Host $Test
```

I Wrote the below PowerShell script to perform the same.

```bsh
$AttribureReportName = "File4.rdl"

foreach ($item in $Test) {
    if ($item.Name -eq $AttribureReportName) {
        $FinalFolder = $item.Path
        Write-Output $FinalFolder 
    }
}
```

As I have too many XML tags it was taking long time perform the operation. Is there any better way to do the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, this is wrong:

```
[xml]$XmlDocument = Get-Content "D:\Roshan\Testing\Test1.xml"
```

Don't load XML files this way, this can cause encoding issues. XML parsers have a well thought-out automatic encoding detection mechanism. `Get-Content` does not have that, so there is a good chance that the XML file is loaded with the wrong encoding and data inside gets corrupted.

Use the XML parser to load the file.

```
$XmlDocument = New-Object xml
$XmlDocument.Load("D:\Roshan\Testing\Test1.xml")
```

After that, you can use XPath to pick the right node from the file. This will be much faster than writing any Powershell loops yourself (`Where-Object` also is a loop).

```
$File = $XmlDocument.SelectSingleNode("/Tag1/Tag2/File[@Name = 'File4.rdl']")
Write-Host $File.Path
```

Comment: Could you please give a small example on how to use "where-object" plz ?

Comment: @Roshan Using `SelectSingleNode()` with an XPath expression is the appropriate solution for the problem described in your question.

Answer (score 2):

As your `Name` attribute should be compared in a Case-Insensitive mode, I suggest something like this:

```
[xml]$xml = @"
<Tag1>
<Tag2>      
  <file Name="file1.rdl" Path="folder34" />
  <File Name="file2.rdl" Path="folder37" />
  <File Name="file3.rdl" Path="folder34" />
  <File Name="File4.rdl" Path="folder76" />
  <File Name="file5.rdl" Path="folder37" />
</Tag2>
</Tag1>
"@

$AttribureReportName = "File4.rdl"

foreach ($item in ($xml.Tag1.Tag2.file | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq $AttribureReportName})) {
    $item.Path
}
```